# Apache setup for multiple sites with common files

Tags: php, apache, vhosts, suexec

I have approx  50 sites that all use the exact same files other than CSS and IMAGES, i currently duplicate the files each time i create a new site and upload different css and images.

What I want do so set up each vhost to have the same ***DocumentRoot*** then add ***AliasMatch*** for the css and images folders e.g:

```
#Common Files VHOST
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    ServerName commonfiles.com
    ServerAlias www.commonfiles.com
    DocumentRoot /home/commonfiles/public_html
</VirtualHost>

#Sample vhost for 1 of the 50 sites.
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    ServerName mytest.com
    ServerAlias www.mytest.com
    DocumentRoot /home/commonfiles/public_html
    ......
    AliasMatch /css/(.*) /home/ftpuser/public_html/mycss/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

The alias works perfectly for the bespoke files but the common files cant be accessed because of permission errors:

```
[Mon Nov 16 09:31:01 2009] [crit] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] (13)Permission denied: /home/commonfiles/public_html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

This is the current server setup which I think may be part of the problem (Previous Server Admin Set this up):

- Apache(Apache/2.2.14 (Unix)
- PHP 5.2.11
- CentOS 4.8 i686 standard
- PHP 5 Handler is dso
- Apache suEXEC is on

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that by default the the public_html folder has permissions of 750, I changed to 755 and updated the open_basedir restrictions and all started to work great.

I just have to make sure that I can still have a .htaccess per site.

Comment: I would but you have to wait 48 hours before you can accept your own answer

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like the AliasMatch is the problem, the error message is pointing to your htaccess file. Have you checked that for permissions? Wbich user does it belong to?

Comment: Yeah the alias match is fine, Example: /home/commonfiles/public_html/.htaccess has 644 commonfiles:commonfiles

Comment: Try giving the whole directory 644. Does that help?

Comment: Changing directory to 644 didn't help, so as a test i set .htaccess and public_html to 777 this then gave me a seperate error `PHP Fatal error:  Can't load /home/commonfiles/public_html/index.php, open_basedir restriction. in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: I just added the correct path to php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/ftpuser:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp:/home/commonfiles" ANd with 777 permissions it is working

Comment: It appears that others needs to have execute permissions, in order for this to work, what permissions should I be using?

Comment: I don't think you need execute permissions for others. Read permissions should work fine. The open_basedir restriction should be a different matter. Check your php.ini, is there an open_basedir configured? If so, try turning it off.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to create symbolic links on each domain pointing to the folder where the common files reside.